# How can we provide the path for the image file in order to create the multimedia component in server?

Tags: tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I am trying to Create  a multimedia Component where
 
1) I am executing my code in client machine
2)Target where it should create a component is one of the test server.
3)Here i am using the http Coreservices added as the Service Reference.
but the part in which i am getting error is the path for the image file for the multimedia component.
Case:1) I am selecting the Image file from the client machine - 
In this case i am getting error in the component creation stage stated:

> Unable to get file size of 'file:///C:foldername/image.jpg'
>  Could
>   not find a part of the path 'C:\foldername\image.jpg'.

Case:2) I mapped the test Server in client machine so it created the Z drive and i am selecting the image file

In this case i am getting same error at component creation stage:

> Unable to get file size of 'file:///Z:/foldername/image.jpg'
>  Could
>   not find a part of the path 'Z:\foldername\image.jpg'.

My question is , **How can we provide the path for the image file in order to create the multimedia component?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer and able to create the multimedia component to the target server:
have used

> StreamUpload2010Client streamClient = new StreamUpload2010Client();

and stored the file at templocation and uploaded it from there.

thanks

Comment: You may want to start using http://tridion.stackexchange.com for all your Tridion questions...